# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; (driver.get)

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
class meet
{
    public static void main()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

i am new to selenium please help

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\piyush\Desktop\New folder\meet\meet\chromedriver
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at meet.main(meet.java:12)

Comment: Property name is `webdriver.chrome.driver` not `webdrivers.chrome.driver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property name is `webdriver.chrome.driver` not `webdrivers.chrome.driver`

Answer (score 0):

please add the extension as well. It should be Chromedriver.exe